# Invalid selenium element selector in angularjs page using c#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I spun up my app locally on port "x" and trying to start my UI testing using selenium. First test case is logging in as an administrator onto the page. The front-end of the app is using Angularjs. I'm trying to target the input field username but I keep running into errors of "Invalid element sector".

I have also tried below but it didn't work either:

```
IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-model='vm.username']"));
```

[image: input field tag of username]

[image: c# code]

Answer (score 0):

The element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  IWebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.form-group.has-feedback > input[name='username'][ng-model='vm.username']")));
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  IWebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-group has-feedback']/input[@name='username' and @ng-model='vm.username']")));
  ```

---

### Nuget Package

If you are using the nuget packages you need to use `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions` as follows:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  IWebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.form-group.has-feedback > input[name='username'][ng-model='vm.username']")));
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  IWebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-group has-feedback']/input[@name='username' and @ng-model='vm.username']")));
  ```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "ExpectedConditions does not exist in current context"?

Comment: Neverminded i solved it by adding the selenium support nug pkg. Thank you !!

Comment: @rjimenez52 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.